# Cassandra 3 node cluster gossip protocol issue due to network fluctuation

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I've got Cassandra 3.7 cluster of 3 nodes with the keyspace replication factor of 3.

All the 3 nodes are started and are in sync. When one of the cassandra node went down, I restarted it, the node gets in sync with the other node.

Now my question is when one of the node has issues like frequent fluctuation in network (cassandra is still up and running).
Say node 1 is having network issues, the nodetool status on the other 2 nodes shows that the node 1 is down. When the network is back on the node 1
the nodetool status shows that the other nodes are down.

Below are the configuration changes I made in the cassandra.yaml files.

`Node 01
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
num_tokens: 256
seed_provider: 
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "10.1.1.4,10.1.1.5,10.1.1.6"
listen_address: 10.1.1.4 
broadcast_address: 10.1.1.4
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
broadcast_rpc_address: 10.1.1.4

Node02
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
num_tokens: 256
seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "10.1.1.4,10.1.1.5,10.1.1.6"
listen_address: 10.1.1.5
broadcast_address: 10.1.1.5
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
broadcast_rpc_address: 10.1.1.5

Node03
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
num_tokens: 256
seed_provider: 
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "10.1.1.4,10.1.1.5,10.1.1.6"
listen_address: 10.1.1.6
broadcast_address: 10.1.1.6
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
broadcast_rpc_address: 10.1.1.6`

Nodetool status on node 1 when the network is up shows that the other nodes are down (DN).

Nodetool status on the other nodes shows that the node 1 is down (DN)

How does the gossip protocol work in this scenario?

Why the node 1 is not in sync with the other nodes when the network is up?

Please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance,

GKK

Comment: Either your network is funky or your nodes are overloaded and flapping. Check out the gc logs and tp stats. Keep an eye on the gossip thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are using the [Ec2MultiRegionSnitch](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/architecture/archSnitchEC2MultiRegion.html) snitch if you are using AWS, or the snitch appropriate.

Also, if you are using AWS, the public IP address may be different to the private one, in which case you may need to modify the `listen_address:` and `broadcast_address:` values accordingly.

Finally for the `seeds` value, I would omit the source IP as part of the seed, in other words:

`Node 01
...
seed_provider: 
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "10.1.1.5,10.1.1.6"
listen_address: 10.1.1.4 
...`

`Node02
...
seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "10.1.1.4,10.1.1.6"
listen_address: 10.1.1.5
...`

`Node03
...
seed_provider: 
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "10.1.1.4,10.1.1.5"
listen_address: 10.1.1.6
...`

Answer (score 0):

Try to lower the number of the seeds. 1 or 2 should be enough. By the way, use same seed list on all nodes.